FFmpeg player backporting to Android 2.1 - one more problem
I looked for a lot of information about how to build and use FFmpeg in early versions of Android, looked at the source codes of players from 2011-2014 and was able to easily build FFmpeg 4.0.4 and 3.1.4 on the NDKv5 platform. I have highlighted the main things for this purpose:

<android/bitmap.h> and <android/native_window.h> before Android 2.2 (API Level 8) such a thing did not exist
this requires some effort to implement buffer management for A/V streams, since in practice, when playing video, the application silently crashed after a few seconds due to overflow (below code example in C++ and Java)
FFmpeg - imho, the only way to support a sufficient number of codecs that are not officially included in Android 2.1 and above

void decodeVideoFromPacket(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                           jclass mplayer_class, AVPacket avpkt, 
                           int total_frames, int length) {
    AVFrame     *pFrame = NULL
    AVFrame     *pFrameRGB = NULL;
    pFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    pFrameRGB = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    int frame_size = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB32, gVideoCodecCtx->width, gVideoCodecCtx->height);
    unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)av_malloc((size_t)frame_size * 3);
    if (!buffer) {
        av_free(pFrame);
        av_free(pFrameRGB);
        return;
    }
    jbyteArray buffer2;
    jmethodID renderVideoFrames = env->GetMethodID(mplayer_class, "renderVideoFrames", "([BI)V");
    int frameDecoded;
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture*) pFrame,
                   buffer,
                   gVideoCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                   gVideoCodecCtx->width,
                   gVideoCodecCtx->height
                  );

    if (avpkt.stream_index == gVideoStreamIndex) { // If video stream found
        int size = avpkt.size;
        total_frames++;
        struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx = NULL;
        avcodec_decode_video2(gVideoCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameDecoded, &avpkt);
        if (!frameDecoded || pFrame == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            PixelFormat pxf;
            // RGB565 by default for Android Canvas in pre-Gingerbread devices.
            if(android::get_android_api_version(env) >= ANDROID_API_CODENAME_GINGERBREAD) {
                pxf = PIX_FMT_BGR32;
            } else {
                pxf = PIX_FMT_RGB565;
            }

            int rgbBytes = avpicture_get_size(pxf, gVideoCodecCtx->width,
                                            gVideoCodecCtx->height);

            // Converting YUV to RGB frame & RGB frame to char* buffer 
            
            buffer = convertYuv2Rgb(pxf, pFrame, rgbBytes); // result of av_image_copy_to_buffer()

            if(buffer == NULL) {
                return;
            }

            buffer2 = env->NewByteArray((jsize) rgbBytes);
            env->SetByteArrayRegion(buffer2, 0, (jsize) rgbBytes,
                                    (jbyte *) buffer);
            env->CallVoidMethod(instance, renderVideoFrames, buffer2, rgbBytes);
            env->DeleteLocalRef(buffer2);
            free(buffer);
        } catch (...) {
            if (debug_mode) {
                LOGE(10, "[ERROR] Render video frames failed");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void renderVideoFrames(final byte[] buffer, final int length) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Canvas c;
                VideoTrack track = null;
                for (int tracks_index = 0; tracks_index < tracks.size(); tracks_index++) {
                    if (tracks.get(tracks_index) instanceof VideoTrack) {
                        track = (VideoTrack) tracks.get(tracks_index);
                    }
                }
                if (track != null) {
                    int frame_width = track.frame_size[0];
                    int frame_height = track.frame_size[1];
                    if (frame_width > 0 && frame_height > 0) {
                        try {
                            // RGB_565  == 65K colours (16 bit)
                            // RGB_8888 == 16.7M colours (24 bit w/ alpha ch.)
                            int bpp = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9 ? 16 : 24;
                            Bitmap.Config bmp_config =
                                    bpp == 24 ? Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 : Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                            Paint paint = new Paint();
                            if(buffer != null && holder != null) {
                                holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
                                if((c = holder.lockCanvas()) == null) {
                                    Log.d(MPLAY_TAG, "Lock canvas failed");
                                    return;
                                }
                                ByteBuffer bbuf =
                                        ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(minVideoBufferSize);
                                bbuf.rewind();
                                for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                                    bbuf.put(i, buffer[i]);
                                }
                                bbuf.rewind();

                                // The approximate location where the application crashed.
                                Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(frame_width, frame_height, bmp_config);
                                bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(bbuf);
                                
                                float aspect_ratio = (float) frame_width / (float) frame_height;
                                int scaled_width = (int)(aspect_ratio * (c.getHeight()));
                                c.drawBitmap(bmp,
                                        null,
                                        new RectF(
                                                ((c.getWidth() - scaled_width) / 2), 0,
                                                ((c.getWidth() - scaled_width) / 2) + scaled_width,
                                                c.getHeight()),
                                        null);
                                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                                bmp.recycle();
                                bbuf.clear();
                            } else {
                                Log.d(MPLAY_TAG, "Video frame buffer is null");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
                            oom.printStackTrace();
                            stop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

Exception (tested in Android 4.1.2 emulator):
E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 1228812-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm: "Thread-495" prio=5 tid=21 RUNNABLE
   ................................................
     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:620)
     at [app_package_name].MediaPlayer$5.run(MediaPlayer.java:406)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

For clarification: I first compiled FFmpeg 0.11.x on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from my written build script, looked for player examples suitable for Android below 2.2 (there is little information about them, unfortunately) and opened the file on the player and after showing the first frames it crashed into a stack or buffer overflow, on I put off developing the player for some time.
Is there anything ready-made that, as a rule, fits into one C++ file and takes into account all the nuances of backporting? Thanks in advance.

Old versions of Android were really subject to the 'fragmentation' by OEMs. Any media player testing would be done on physical devices as the emulator (QEMU based) was seldom up to the task. Just in case, for playing video, investigating old versions of VLC-Android may be of interest.

But when I looked at the APK file of the old VKontakte client from 2013, which, oddly enough, also had FFmpeg with its own player (libvkplayer.so), similar questions arise. Maybe I went a little overboard with my codes, even then it could work calmly.

How to properly port a player to Android 2.2 and lower?
To make sure that you can write a player, you need to do the following:

Before FFmpeg build use Android NDK r8e for 32-bit build and Android NDK r10e for 64-bit build.
Since in NDK r10e building for Android 2.0 platform is still possible, but running the library in Android 2.1 will lead to the application crashing in SIGSEGV due to the incorrect libc runtime.

I actually didn't know about the existence of the ReleaseByteArrayElements function in JNI, so it was a big help in figuring out why the buffer was overflowing.

The av_packet_unref, av_free_packet, sws_freeContext FFmpeg functions are extremely important and should be inserted at the end of each decoded frame.


In practice, this is exactly what happened:
Before:
~160 MB memory per minute of video 
After:
~25 MB memory on average
